# Save virtualenv variable on linux

Tags: python, linux, bash, virtualenv

I use Linux (Ubuntu 14). I need to save a variable to my virtualenv, so I write on the bash shell with the virtualenv activated:

```
$ export SECRET_KEY='asdgladfkga....'
```

and then I can do (using python):

```
import os
key = os.environ["SECRET_KEY"]
```

Everything works fine until I restart the computer, then, the variable is erased. How do I truly save it? can I do this without installing virtualenvwrapper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the SECRET_KEY variable to be defined only when you activate your virtualenv, then you could modify the `preactivate` script in your virtualenv `bin` directory by adding

```
export SECRET_KEY='asdgladfkga....'
```

Comment: didn't find the "preactivate" script, but found one named "activate". and it worked. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a *virtualenv* issue. *virtualenv* is meant to sandbox your *Python* environment. Running the *activate* script, which you `source`, does change some environment variables at the OS level, but those are not saved/sandboxed, and are not connected to the virtualenv itself other than in the current instance of the shell in which you ran *activate*.

When you reboot, your *.bashrc* will load your *bash* environment back up based on the contents of that file.

If you wanted to keep a "secret key" -- offhand, I'm not sure I get why you want to do this;  what are you trying to accomplish? -- you could have a wrapper script that:

1. Set the key in the current shell via `EXPORT`
2. `echo`s the key to a file in your home directory with the same `EXPORT` command

Then, you could modify your *.bashrc* to `source` that file if it exists, so it would get loaded on startup, and therefore survive reboots.

When the *virtualenv* wrapper was run again, the process would repeat (and not change anything functionally if the key didn't change; you could optimize it to not bother setting the variable again nor write out the file if the key is the same).